# I can't generate a signed APK

Tags: android, signed-apk

When I try to generate a signed APK I'm getting an error.

The error log:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':HoppingMouse:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bb.HoppingMouse"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
}
```

build.gradle Module:googleplayservices_lib

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

Comment: You appear to be loading in two copies of the same Android support library, in some way that Gradle cannot reconcile. I suggest that you edit your question and post your module's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I added build.gradle file

Comment: My guess is that `libs/android-support-v4.jar` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0` are going to conflict. I recommend replacing both JARs with artifact dependencies (e.g., replace `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` with `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:...'` for some value of `...`). Right now, your `compileSdkVersion` is a few years old, and that will make it difficult for you to do modern Android app development.

Comment: Thank you my problem is solved thank you alot